# Drive not detected on 14.04.1 server install for Western Digital drive

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, hardware

Ubuntu cannot locate my hard drive (WD6402AAEX) during install.  Hard drive works fine under Win7 x64.  Bios and cabling is fine.

Am I missing something?  I don't see Linux drivers on the WD website and nothing in the manually selecting list looks right.  Does Western digital not run Linux?

Comment: Welcome to AU! What kernel version and chipset do you have? This is likely a chipset driver issue that's fixed in newer kernels. Please [append](https://askubuntu.com/posts/531833/edit) the output of `uname -a` and `lspci` to your question. Hard drives generally don't have individual drivers on Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Seems like the 6Gbps SATA ports on my Asus Motherboard aren't recognized under Ubuntu.  Moving the HDD to the regular SATA ports worked.